# In CodeBlocks 16 Without using wxWidgets DLL, fatal error: wx/setup.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, dll, youtube, wxwidgets

I am new in wxWidgets. Yesterday I was trying 15 times to configure wxWidgets on my codeBlocks 16. I caould not succeed. Today i saw a video from youtube link [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmobZRIlBMU) and was able to compile with wxWidgets DLL. Here is a problem, the executable file doesn't execute without wxmsw30u_gcc_custom.dll.

And I also saw that without using wxWidgets DLL it shows fatal error: wx/setup.h: No such file or directory. But another video [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QuPiZ86EFhQ) shows that it works without wxWidgets DLL but my codeBlocks show this error.

How can i solve that problem ?

C++ is my favourite programming language and i want to learn C++ GUI programming. please help me.

Comment: Ensure there is a directory wx in your include path containing setup.h. Ensure that the required dll is in the same directory as the executable file. Also if implicitly linked the dll is(compile time instead of runtime), then you will require a .lib with the same name as the .dll also ensure that the .lib is linked correctly in the makefile or how ever you set that up. Hope this helps.

Comment: I dont mostly use CodeBlocks and prefer Eclipse. But if you go to Project Options--> Project Build Options then go to search directories tab and add `WXWIDGETSINSTALLATION\lib\gcc_dll\mswu` to compiler section and `WXWIDGETSINSTALLATION\lib\gcc_dll` to your linker section it shuld compile.

Comment: Dear @macroland it shows another problem.

cannot find -lwxmsw30ud
cannot find -lwxpngd
cannot find -lwxjpegd
cannot find -lwxtiffd
cannot find -lwxzlibd
error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: if you have installed wxWidgets as monolithic, then you should select monolithic option in CodeBlocks

Comment: Thanks everyone. After reading this two pages, i can solve my problem.

http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_Code::Blocks_from_source_on_Windows#zip.exe

and 

https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=41903